# Does Julia's Plotly backend support basic animation or buttons?

Tags: animation, plotly, julia, julia-plots

I'm new-ish to Julia, and the docs & discourse make a big deal about integration with Plot.ly, but without mentioning the standard Plotly feature of animated figures with control widgets.

Is is possible to create, for example, the classic Our World In Data figure with an animated slider, as one could in any other Plotly interface, including Python, R, Javascript, or Chart Studio?

[image: Standar OWID Plot]

(See Python example at https://plotly.com/python/animations/)

P.S. - I've seen that Interact.jl has (1) buttons, (2) manual sliders, and (3) video export. Ideally, I'd like to use Plotly, but if there's a way to mash the various modules together, I'd settle for it.